# Infinite Ramification Places of Finite Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

Let $F/K$ be an algebraic function field, with constant field $K=K_{F}$, and $L/F$ be an finite extension.

**Is it possible that infinitely many places of $L$ ramifiy?**

Somehow I feel that it is not possible because $L/F$ is finite, but I am not very clear why. I would appreciate if anyone can provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an inseparable extension, every place is ramified. If the extension is separable, then only finitely many places ramify.

One can argue as follows: Think of this geometrically, i.e. we have a finite morphism of curves $D\to C$, then one can show that the support of $\Omega^1_{D/C}$ consists exactly of the ramified primes, but this a closed subset and a proper subset if the function field extension is separable, thus it consists of finitely many points.

This whole argument also works in the more general setting of Dedekind schemes, e.g. $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal O_K)$ for a number field $K$.